# plotly in R: Box selection for plot with many lines

Tags: r, plotly

I am trying to create a plot in plot_ly in R that has many lines. I would like to be able to use the selection tool as well. An example is below:

```
library(plotly)

trace_0 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_1 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
trace_2 <- rnorm(100, mean = 0)
x <- c(1:100)

data <- data.frame(x, trace_0, trace_1, trace_2)

plot_ly(data, x = ~x, y = ~trace_0, name = 'trace 0', type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_1, name = 'trace 1', mode = 'lines') %>%
  add_trace(y = ~trace_2, name = 'trace 2', mode = 'lines')
```

Based on this example, I have two questions in terms of tailoring it to my goal:

1) In the example above, the dimensions of the data was 100 rows and 4 columns. Let's say I had a data frame that was 100 rows and 50 columns. Is there a better method to add each of the new lines (by add_trace), or would I need to do that in a for-loop for 49 lines?

2) Is there a way I could still obtain the "select" option. Sometimes, when using plot_ly, there is a box and lasso selection tool that appears. However, for some reason, I am unable to get that by default with this plot at hand.

If you have any suggestions toward either of these goals, I would greatly appreciate your input! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
library(plotly)
library(reshape2)
# some reproducible data
d <- cbind.data.frame(x=1:nrow(iris), iris[,-5])
  x Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1 1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2 2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3 3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4 4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5 5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6 6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
# transform to long format using reshape's melt() function  
d_long <- melt(d, id.vars ="x" )
# plot the lines using the group argument for different traces.
plot_ly(d_long, x=  x, y=value, group= variable, type= "line")
```

[image]

A solution for the second question could be the `dragmode`. Add one of these values to your plot:

```
c("zoom", "pan", "select", "lasso", "orbit", "turntable")
plot_ly(d_long, x=  x, y= value, group= variable, type= "line") %>%
  layout(dragmode = "lasso")
```

Check also the layout reference on the [plotly website](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#Layout_and_layout_style_objects). But I'm not sure whether the icons

**Edit:**

The newest plotly version `plotly_4.5.2` changed the syntax a little bit. Now you have to specify the `type` to `"scatter"` or `"scattergl"` and the `mode` to `"line"` for a line plot. The group argument will be set by color or by `group_by()`. Unfortunatly there is no `"lasso"` or `"select`" function in the line-mode at all. Therfore you have to use the `"lines+markers"` mode. With the dragmode you can specify which feature is preselected.

```
plot_ly(d_long, x=  ~x, y= ~value, type = 'scatter', mode = 'lines+markers', color = ~variable)  %>% layout(dragmode="lasso")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I should have stated more clearly that I wanted to use the select option so that it would highlight any lines that were covered (while deselecting the rest). In this example, it seems that it highlights the dot markers when selected. You seemed to indicate that plot_ly doesn't allow for box/lasso selections on lines alone (which may be what I want). I wonder if there is another way around it?

Comment: I tried using a developing R package called "crosstalk". I believe there were some working examples for this (https://github.com/jcheng5/plotly/blob/joe/feature/crosstalk/inst/examples/crosstalk/01-intro.R), which I had working a month or so ago. However, when I tried to run those examples again, I got an error that the "crosstalk" function could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
p<-plot_ly(y=trace_0, x=x , evaluate=TRUE)
p<-add_trace(y=trace_1, x=x , evaluate=TRUE)
p<-add_trace(y=trace_2, x=x , evaluate=TRUE)
p
```

[image]